# How to send data/variable from one method to another in the same controller in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I have 2 functions/methods in the same controller in Laravel like this..

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
//use App\Http\Requests\CreatRole;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Input;
use Redirect;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\UserRole;

class UserController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function role()
    {

        return view('user.role');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function roleProcess(Requests\CreatRole $request)
    {
            $input = Input::all();
            $role = new UserRole;
            $role->role_name = Input::get('role-name');
            $role->role_number = Input::get('role-number');
            $role->save();

            //redirect to add page;
            return Redirect::to('/home/role/add')->with('message','Role is added');

    }


}
```

And My routes.php have route as

```
Route::get('/home/role/add','UserController@role');
```

What I am trying to do is adding  and listing the role can be done  from same view i.e on the same web page. I want to show the success message when the role is added. I think to do this we have to passes the success message from roleProcess to role but I don't know how to pass the variables or data from one method to another in laravel.

Comment: you want show success message and listing data to same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I did not misunderstand your question.

you want the word "Role is added" to be shown in "user.role" view after the form submitted.

try to put following code inside "user.role" view

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
  {{ Session::get('message') }}
@endif
```